# Using Freemarker templates and the JSF 2.x resources folder for media

Tags: jsf-2, resources, html-email, freemarker, template-engine

I have a JSF 2.x application that sends emails using Freemarker templates.

My problem is best described as follows:

- from my Freemarker template, I refer to a media/image that is hosted on the JSF website;
- my resources are in a "**jsf2.x**" `resources` folder;
- Of course, I can't use the `<h:graphicImage library="images" name="logo.gif" ...` syntax from my Freemarker template...

Has anyone got any solution?

I am supposed to attach the image to the email?

Or am I supposed to use two locations for my images/media (one public and the other under the `resources` folder)?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there are a few unrelated questions here.

One question is attaching images VS referring to them via URL in email. I don't think this was ever decided, it depends on many things. I say, if the image is not just decoration, but something that the recipient wants to keep in his mail archive (like a diagram), embedding is the only way, unless you can guarantee that the image URL will still work months or years later. If its decoration only... that's tricky. Last time I checked, mail clients block loading images from an URL by default. Users has to click on them or something to enable loading them, but maybe they can enable images from a sender permanently. But if the image is not important, most users just will not care, and will never see them. Attaching images is more bullet-proof in this regard, but it increases the size of the mail (not very polite), and increases the possibility of false spam positives (spammers often use images for text).

Another question is the JSF/FreeMarker related one. I don't know JSF... but unless it's a horrible design, it has to have Java API-s through which you can get the resource URL (if you want to refer to it in the mail), or read the resource (if you want to attach it to the mail). Then from the FreeMarker template you can call the Java methods of objects that you have put into the data-model, so you can add some helper object from which FreeMarker can get the URL or the base64-encoded content. (If you can't/don't want to add to the data-model, you can still create `TemplateDirectiveModel` or `TemplateMethodModelEx` implementations and pull them in like `<#assign resourceContentB64 = 'com.example.ResourceContentB64Directive'?new()>`.)